# Use a custom function as argument to Ecto order_by

Tags: mysql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, levenshtein-distance

I have a function `distance/2` which calculates the [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between two strings.

I would like to use this as an argument for `order_by/3` ([documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#order_by/3)), so that the result be ordered by Levenshtein distance to a term, as I am trying to implement a rudimentary autocomplete.

Currently, I have something like:

```
Api.Repo.all(from p in Api.Product, select: p.name, order_by: distance(p.name, ^term), where: p.company_id == ^company_id)
```

however this errors, stating that:

`'distance(p.name ^term)' is not a valid query expression.`

I have also tried moving the `^` to before the function like so:

```
Api.Repo.all(from p in Api.Product, select: p.name, order_by: ^distance(p.name, term), where: p.company_id == ^company_id)
```

however then I get a complaint that `p/0` is undefined.

Is there a way to use my function as an argument to `order_by/3`?

Comment: If your `distance` function is not in PostGres, then there's no way to affect the ordering until after you'd returned all rows because the function would need to have all available data returned to it *before* it could perform a calculation on it.  See Dogbert's answer for an example of how to sort a list of records.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call an Elixir function from within a query like that. You'll either have to use a function that [your database allows in queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/functions.html) or do the sorting after fetching all data into Elixir. The second method can be done like this:

```
products =
  Api.Repo.all(from p in Api.Product, select: p.name, where: p.company_id == ^company_id)
  |> Enum.sort_by(&distance(&1, term))
```